# Проверка является ли число степенью 2, на 0 ничего не выводит

Tags: java

учусь Java. Одно из заданий написать программу, которая будет проверять является ли число степенью двойки. Я написал следующий код, но на 0 он ничего не выводит и я не понимаю почему.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int namber = 0;
        namber = Math.abs(namber);
        boolean yesNoot;
        while (namber%2==0){
            namber=namber/2;
        }
        if (namber !=1)
            yesNoot = false;
        else
            yesNoot = true;
        System.out.println(yesNoot);
```

При чём другой вариант решения, который я нашёл в интернете реагирует на 0 точно также:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input num: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();

        while (num != 1 && num % 2 == 0) {
            num /= 2;
        }

        System.out.println(num == 1 ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
```

Comment: ну и в какой степени 2 будет 0?

Comment: Никакой, должно выдавать false

Comment: посмотрите по шагам вы поймете где ошибка

Comment: Может быть дело в том, что 0 можно бесконечно делить на 0 с остатком 0 и из-за этого программа просто выключается когда доходит до этого?

Comment: Все значительно проще. Никакие циклы не нужны, достаточно одного выражения -- `System.out.println(num == 0 || (num & (num - 1)) != 0 ? "NO" : "YES");`, поскольку в побитном представлении целого числа степень двойки это всегда ровно одна 1 в каком-то разряде. При вычитании единицы из степени двойки этот разряд станет нулем, а все разряды младшие него станут единичками. И битовая операция `&` (.AND.) для любой такой комбинации даст 0.

Comment: @avp, `num == 0` -> `num <= 0`. Отрицательные надо исключить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в самом деле (спасибо!). Привык при работе с битами иметь дело с  unsigned  (коих вроде бы в Java нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input num: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    while (num != 1 && num % 2 == 0 && num > 0) {
        num /= 2;
    }

    System.out.println(num == 1 ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

или так как предложил @Grundy

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input num: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    while (num > 1 && num % 2 == 0) {
        num /= 2;
    }

    System.out.println(num == 1 ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

Comment: Да, так заработало. Спасибо. Дело было в том, что при нуле while мог бы крутится бесконечно и программа не запускалась?

Comment: Ну это мне понятно, рад помочь

Comment: !=1 и > 0 можно совместить в `>1`

Comment: @Grundy да конечно, обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Самый быстрый вариант, это посмотреть на биты в числе. Если "включён" (равен единице) только один бит, число - степень двойки.

```java
private void isPowerOfTwo(int number) {
    if (Integer.bitCount(number) == 1 && number > 0) {
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

На основе этого можно быстро найти следующую ближайшую степень двойки относительно вводимого числа. Нужно лишь взять самый высокий (левый бит) и сместить его ещё левее.

```java
private void nextPowerOfTwo(int number) {
    if (Integer.bitCount(number) == 1 && number > 0) {
        // здесь используется long для того, чтобы при смещении бита у нас не переполнился int
        // актуально если ввести число Integer.MAX_VALUE
        long highestBit = Integer.highestOneBit(number);
        System.out.println(highestBit << 1);
    } else {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пожалуйста - универсальный метод по определению - является ли число степенью двойки.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = -2;
        isPowerOfTwo(a);
      }
    public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int value) {
        if (Integer.bitCount(Math.abs(value)) == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Этот вариант фактически уже есть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1423379/1365

Comment: Там не берётся модуль числа, в связи с чем ответ данный выше не верен.

Comment: В какую степень нужно возвести двойку чтобы получить *-4*?

Comment: Старый ответ ошибался только для одного значения. Ваш ошибается для всех степеней двойки со знаком минус. Это определённо ухудшение.

Comment: Не затрагивая комплексные числа, число в степени не может быть отрицательным.

Comment: @Drugs, отрицательное число в нечетной степени остается отрицательным